# Sending Data to OpenSplice (DDS)

Tags: data-distribution-service, opensplice

I'm new to DDS and opensplice, so this may be simple, but I don't understand it.

I am reading about reader caches and writer caches in the opensplice documentation. I understand that data goes into the datawriter cache and is then sent to datareader caches. But how do you push the information you have to the datawriter cache in the first place?

Is there a seperate command for that or does data automatically get sent to the cache when you publish or subscribe a device or application to a topic?

I guess in all, my question is, how does data get into opensplice/ the datawriter cache?

I appreciate any help. Like I said, I've been reading through tutorials and reference guides. I see plenty about what happens when the info is in opensplice, but I can't figure out how you put it there. If possible, could you link to an example too please?

Thanks

Comment: Did you look at the [OpenSplice examples](https://github.com/PrismTech/opensplice/tree/master/examples) and/or [documentation](https://github.com/PrismTech/opensplice/tree/master/docs/pdf)?

Comment: I commented on the answer. I was looking at documentation I found online, but I never thought to check GitHub for more. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually .. its as simple as doing a write() or read() for your topic, so its a straightforward API call to provide 'samples' to DDS (i.e. publishing data) or to extract 'samples' from DDS (i.e. reading subscribed data).

As Reinier suggested too, it typically helps to look at some of the bundled examples (you could start with the famous 'HelloWorld") on how to create the publisher/subscriber and reader/writer 'entities' that allow you to interact with DDS from your application (in its 'language of choice')

Note: the examples are located here (for a 32-bit linux installation):
 /HDE/x86.linux/examples/dcps/

The source for the Helloworld example (for Java) would then be here:
/HDE/x86.linux/examples/dcps/HelloWorld/java/src

Comment: I have be looking at the C++ Reference Guide and different slide shows like this one: http://www.slideshare.net/Angelo.Corsaro/20-tips-for-opensplice-newbies. I didn't think to check GitHub for more documentation and examples. I feel like it was really obvious now, but thanks for helping me out anyway!